# Dropbox systray icon not showing in KDE4

Tags: debian, kde

I have Jessie Debian 8.4

I installed dropbox, but the icon in the systray is not present.

How can I put it?

[image: Show this :|]

Answer (score 3):

I am using Debian Jessie 8.5 (KDE 4.14.2), but had this problem since 8.0. I was lucky to find [this workaround](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=128419).

Just create a script like this in **~/.kde/Autostart**:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start
```

I am not exactly sure why this works so if anyone can explain, it would be much appreciated.

If that doesn't do it, you can just append the last line to **~/.profile**. That should work reliably.

---

**Update:** Thanks to the [new information from *cipricus*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290761/79861) the solution now boils down to merely editing the `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. It should be enough to just replace:

`Exec=dropbox start`

with:

`Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start`

Comment: @cipricus `This will start Dropbox with the system.` -- What does it mean exactly? Why are the GUI options not available when it is started in a different way?

Comment: What I meant was: if you don't want to start the app with the system the script should not be put in `~/.kde/Autostart` (odd choice but it happened to be mine). To have the systray icon one still has to run the script (copied in some other location). (Starting with the system is default expected behavior for Dropbox.) -- If I don't want to start it with the system &  don't use the script but a different way (the 'normal' manual way, like a launcher), the systray icon  (therefore the GUI) will not be visible, while the app will be in fact running (visible in the system monitor `ksysguard`).

Comment: Summing it up: 1. if you need the normal behavior to start the app with the system, just follow the answer; 2. if by chance you want to start the app manually put the script in some other location and run it manually.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290761/32012

Comment: @cipricus Thanks for the complete answer. Using the `dbus-launch` command in the Autostart GUI is a much neater solution.

Comment: @cipricus Actually, I have one remark on the solution (sorry, I cannot comment on your answer -- not enough rep ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯). I found out today that when the 'Start Dropbox at system startup' is checked in Dropbox Settings, on my system, it tends to reset the entry (and automatically adds it, if previously removed) in the Autostart KDE Control Module. So after reboot it is not executed with `dbus-launch` again. I guess the safest bet would be to uncheck the box in the Dropbox GUI and provide your own script or desktop file.

Comment: Yes, what happens is that checking the option 'Start Dropbox at system startup' will add Dropbox to the startup list with the command that is set in `usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. This is the command that is executed anyway, so the manual change indicated at the point 1 of my answer is useless. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @cipricus I had no idea the autostart entry actually used `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. Thanks for the new info.

Comment: it was your comment that made me aware of that, as explanation why I didn't have the problem you mentioned: I had already changed the `.desktop` file as indicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complementary answer based on [the other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290344/32012).

It seems that in order to fix this problem Dropbox needs to be started with the command

```
dbus-launch dropbox start
```

(`dropbox stop` in the script was needed considering that Dropbox was supposed to be already running)

- Run "Autostart" in `krunner` (Alt-Space, type 'Autostart') and remove dropbox from the list, or otherwise edit the Application command to `dbus-launch dropbox start`.

(The above step may not be needed, but just in case.)

- Using `gedit` text editor, run in terminal:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`

and then replace the line that starts with `Exec=` like so:

```
Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start
```

If Dropbox was removed from the startup list before, start it manually (with a launcher like `krunner` or with the above mentioned command).

---

**The above is an update to a previous version of this answer:**

A comment on the other answer made by the author of the answer mentions the fact that when only the dropbox startup command is edited in the startup list this is reset after reboot and replaced by the command included in `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. So, the command from this `.desktop` file is the one executed at startup, and therefore is the only change needed.

---

A similar problem appears **in Plasma 5: it can be fixed in the same way.** (Tested in Kubuntu 16.04).